Inequalities in Erdős' paper "Graph Theory and Probability" and possible alternative proof of the main theorem
I am working on graphs with large girth and large chromatic number.
The main theorem in this topic is the one given by Erdős in his paper Graph theory and probability where he says that for every $l$ and $k$ there exists a graph $G$ with $girth(G) > l$ and $\chi(G) \geq k$.
In his proof of this theorem he takes a sufficiently large $n$ and defines $m = \lfloor n^{1+\epsilon} \rfloor$ and $p = \lfloor n^{1-\eta} \rfloor$ where $0 < \epsilon < \frac{1}{k}$ is arbitrary and $0 < \eta < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is arbitrary. A vital part of his proof is the following series of inequalities which he claims to be true for sufficiently large $n$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{\binom{p}{2}}{l}\binom{\binom{n}{2}-\binom{p}{2}}{m-l} &< (n+1)\binom{\binom{p}{2}}{n}\binom{\binom{n}{2}-\binom{p}{2}}{m} < p^{2n}\binom{\binom{n}{2}-\binom{m}{2}}{m} \\
&< \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}p^{2n}\left(1 - \frac{\binom{p}{2}}{\binom{n}{2}}\right)^m < \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}p^{2n}\left(1 - \frac{p^2}{n^2}\right)^m \\
&< \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}p^{2n}\exp{\left(-\frac{mp^2}{n^2}\right)}
\end{align}
However, I believe some of these inequalities are wrong. The first one and the last one are correct but I believe the second one and the second to last are wrong. Because $m$ is larger than $n$, the third expression is negative if $m$ is odd while the second expression is positive, so the second inequality doesn't hold. Also, the fourth expression is always larger than the fifth expression because $\frac{\binom{p}{2}}{\binom{n}{2}} < \frac{p^2}{n^2}$ for any $n$ given that $p = \lfloor n^{1-\eta} \rfloor$. So the second to last inequality doesn't hold either.
So my question is whether the
$$\sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{\binom{p}{2}}{l}\binom{\binom{n}{2}-\binom{p}{2}}{m-l} < \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}p^{2n}\exp{\left(-\frac{mp^2}{n^2}\right)}$$
inequality is true at all and if it is, how does one prove it?
If the inequality isn't correct, is there some other way to prove Erdős' theorem without using this inequality?
P.S.
My question is similar to this question already posted which didn't receive any answers. However, that question is asking how to prove the series of inequalities. I have proved myself that some of these inequalities are incorrect and I am looking for a different proof of the
$$\sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{\binom{p}{2}}{l}\binom{\binom{n}{2}-\binom{p}{2}}{m-l} < \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}p^{2n}\exp{\left(-\frac{mp^2}{n^2}\right)}$$
inequality or a completely different proof of Erdős' theorem if the inequality is incorrect.

It seems to me that the second inequality is a topo ($\binom{p}{2}$ shouldn't be changed to $\binom{m}{2}$). For the second to last inequality, I think you are right but the gap is asymptotically zero and we can make up the gap somewhere else.

As mentioned in the comments, most of the problems with the derivation disappear if we change the third expression from $p^{2n}\binom{\binom{n}{2}-\binom{m}{2}}{m}$ to $p^{2n}\binom{\binom{n}{2}-\binom{p}{2}}{m}$ to match both the second and the fourth expression, which is almost certainly just a typo.
The remaining problem would go away if we simply skipped the next-to-last step and ended with $$\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{m}p^{2n}\exp{\left(-\frac{mp(p-1)}{n(n-1)}\right)}$$ instead, making the derivation correct line-by-line. The gap introduced here is a factor of roughly $e^{mp/n^2}$, which is less than $e^{n^{1/k}}$, so we could maybe justify replacing $\frac{p(p-1)}{n(n-1)}$ by $\frac{p^2}{n^2}$ in the overall inequality by explaining how we've already given away more than that when dropping a factor of $(n+1)/n!$ when going from the second to the third expression.
Or maybe not? I haven't checked, because I think that's missing the point. If you continue reading the paper, you'll see a similar "mistake" appear when replacing $\exp(-\frac{mp^2}{n^2})$ by $\exp(-n^{1+\epsilon - 2\eta})$. Why is this wrong? Because $m$ is not $n^{1+\epsilon}$ but $\lfloor n^{1+\epsilon} \rfloor$, and $p$ is also $\lfloor n^{1-\eta}\rfloor$ and not $n^{1-\eta}$.
But all these differences of changing $m$ to $n^{1+\epsilon}$, changing $p-1$ to $p$ and $p$ to $n^{1-\eta}$, and changing $n-1$ to $n$ amount to nothing substantial. Suppose we take $n$ large enough that $m$, $n$, and $p$ are all at least $100$. Then all of these changes are changes by less than $1\%$, so five of them amount to a less than $5\%$ change in the overal expression even if they all go the same way (they don't). So we should be happy to write $$\exp\left(-\frac{mp(p-1)}{n(n-1)}\right) \le \exp(-0.95 n^{1+\epsilon-2\eta})$$ and the factor of $0.95$ doesn't make a difference. It's going up against $p^{3n} = e^{3n \log p} = \exp(3(1-\eta) n \log n)$, and so all that matters is that $1+\epsilon-2\eta > 1$.

I imagine that Erdős didn't know it yet in 1959, but many of the technical details in this part of the proof go away if we look at random graphs with a fixed edge probability rather than a fixed number of edges. The five-step inequality here is mostly about proving that sampling without replacement has tighter tail bounds than sampling with replacement, so that we can switch from a hypergeometric to a binomial probability, and that's not necessary if we just switch to the binomial probability in the first place.
If you read a modern presentation of the proof - e.g. after Chapter 3 in Alon and Spencer's Probabilistic Method - it ends up shorter and clearer mostly because of changes like this one, whose utility took a long time to become apparent.

Thank you for your help! I am currently studying for an exam but as soon as I get to the proof which you suggested and when I understand it, I will accept your answer.
